# Accessing member functions from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a little problem in using vectors.
I have a vector which stores Staff objects created by Staff class.

```
vector <Staff> staffList;
vector <Staff>::iterator sit;
```

I have added several staff objects into this vector.
My staff class has methods like:

```
Staff getStaffAccount(string);
int getAccessLevel();
string getUserName();
int getStaffID();
string getPassword();
void setStaffIDNumber(int const);
void setUsername(string);
void setPassword(string);
void setAccessLevel(int);
static void changePassword(Staff*);
```

When I need to modify a staff object, what I do is to get the staff object and modify it. This is how I get the staff object:

```
Staff* Staff::searchByID(int staffID){
const int vectorSize = staffList.size();
for (int i=0; i<vectorSize; ++i){
    if (staffList[i].getStaffID() == staffID){
        return &staffList[i];
        break;
        }
    }
return NULL;
}
```

Now after I do changes to the object I have no idea how to save the changed object into the vector. For example I can setPassword() for an staff object, the password is changed as long 
that object is in the memory. But as soon as it is destroyed and loaded again from the vector, password was reset to the previous value which was there in the vector.

- Can I modify staff object while it is in the vector?
- If so, how can I search for staff objects in the vector?
  (To search I came across vector::find method, but I am not sure how to use it on objects.

Comment: Since you are using pointer, you are already changing the original object located in the list

Comment: You should post an SSCCE (see sscce.org) showing how the modifications fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the for loop you can use

```
Staff* Staff::searchByID(int staffID){
    auto i = std::find_if(staffList.begin(), staffList.end(); [staffID](Staff &s) {
       return s.getStaffID() == staffID;
    });

    if(i != staffList.end()) return &(*i);
    return NULL;
}
```

To the actual question. Because you are using a pointer, the original should change.

EDIT: Here is test code: http://ideone.com/HQV6Md

Comment: That really made me laugh. Fixed it :P